# How to remove dots from a string in Java?

Tags: java

In my program I want to remove all the dots(.) I've tried to do this but it's not working.

```
public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            String str = " .Hello.World..Awesome!. ";
            System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".",""));
        }
    }
```

Comment: tl;dr: you may want to use [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). `String::replaceAll` takes a regex as first argument and it just so happens that a `.` in a regex matches any character. Thus, the program does not print anything since each character is replaced with the empty `String`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information!

Answer (score 2):

Replace all takes a regex as the first argument and you need to escape "." like 
"\\."

```
str.replaceAll("\\.","")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because . is a special regex character. You must escape this using a backslash. The dot is used as a capture all in regex.

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\.",""));
```

You can read up on all of the special characters in regex here - https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html